# ruby on rails roo gem cannot load zip/zipfilesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, rubyzip

I am attempting to use the roo gem to process .xlsx spreadsheets that are uploaded by an outside party.  I'm getting the following error:

LoadError (cannot load such file -- zip/zipfilesystem):

I've found a lot of questions similar to this one (such as cannot load such file -- zip/zip) and I've tried to follow their solutions.  So far, to no avail.

I originally required 'roo' in the controller, and after getting this error tried requiring 'zip/zip', 'zip/zipfilesystem', and just 'zip'.  None of these seem to fix anything.  I've also tried adding :require => 'zip', :require => 'zip/zipfilesystem', :require => 'zip/zip' to the Gemfile, and none of that seemed to change anything.  Here is some pertinent code:

in Gemfile:

```
# for spreadsheet upload management
gem 'roo'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'nokogiri'
```

installed versions:

```
nokogiri (1.6.0)
roo (1.12.1)
rubyzip (1.0.0)
spreadsheet (0.8.9)
```

in Controller:

```
require 'roo'

module BatchOrderProcessing
  class DataFilesController < ApplicationController

    def create
      # some code here ...

      when ".xlsx"
        spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(uploaded_io.path, nil, :ignore)
        header = spreadsheet.row(1)
        if # some validation stuff...
          puts "spreadsheet format inappropriate"
          redirect_to # some place
        end
        process_datafile(fname, spreadsheet)
        # more code ...
    end

private

  def process_datafile(fname, spreadsheet)
    @df = DataFile.new
    @df[:filename] = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(fname)

    if @df.save
      begin
        # parse asynchronously
        datafile_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

        datafile_scheduler.in '3s' do
          @df.process_spreadsheet(spreadsheet)
        end
        redirect_to @df
      rescue => e
        # more code ...
      end
    else
       # more code ...
    end
  end
```

I think this thing is crapping out before it gets to the model (where the process_spreadsheet() code is), but just in case, here's some model code:

```
def process_spreadsheet(spreadsheet)
    # do some stuff
    puts "parsing spreadsheet"
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      row_array << row
      invoice << row.to_s

  # some more code....

    dfi = DataFileItem.new()
    dfi.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    dfi.data_file_id = self.id
    dfi.save
    self.data_file_items << dfi

  #  Update stuff in our DB based on rows in row_array...

end
```

I'm using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0.0p195.

Am I requiring the wrong thing (or in the wrong way) somewhere?  Let me know if any other code snippets would be helpful.  Thaaaaanks.

Comment: Have you tried: `gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'` in your `Gemfile`? See readme at https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip

Comment: No... no I haven't.  And that's kind of blatantly right in my face.  It looks like that fixed my problem.  I have another issue popping up, but it appears unrelated.  If you throw that up as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

rubyzip v1.0.0 was released 29 August 2013: https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/releases

This is a new major version number, and more than one gem or project that depends on this has been caught out by the break with backwards-compatibility.

The quickest "get my code working like before" fix is to alter `Gemfile` reference to `rubyzip`:

```
gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'
```

In the longer-term, this may not be the best fix, it depends on how and/or why you are using `rubyzip`. I expect some gem publishers such as `roo`'s authors will need to figure out how to transition nicely so that their own users don't end up with simultaneous requirements for incompatible versions of `rubyzip`.

---

Just opinion:

Seeing this in action has actually made me much less a fan of Ruby gems semantic versioning for major versions. If I ever break with backwards compatibility on any of my own projects, I think I'll just start a new gem, and put a notice on the old gem.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding the [zip-zip](http://rubygems.org/gems/zip-zip) gem to your project. It provides a simple adapter for your dependencies using the RubyZip v0.9.9 interface allowing you to upgrade to RubyZip v1.0.0.

Comment: OMG. I have never expected this would work! but I said, hey, I will give it a try, and it worked! Thanks a lot Orien!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the roo gem. You need to update to version 1.12.2 or higher to fix. See the issue here: https://github.com/Empact/roo/pull/65